# Migrating SharePoint Content database from 2010 to 2013

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2012, sharepoint-2013

Source Environment:
1.) SharePoint 2010
2.) 1 site collection
3.) 8 sites in that site collection.

The requirement i have is to move the site collection along with all the data from 2010 to 2013.

Currently i am planning to migrate the content database.
I have got [this](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/02/07/back-up-content-database-from-sharepoint-2010-and-restore-it-to-sharepoint-2013.aspx) link and i am following it.

But my source server has SQL SERVER 2008 and destination server has SQL SERVER 2012.

Is this correct what i am doing or is there any better way to do this without using content database migration? Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way is database migration.i do this for migration from sp 2007 to 2013.all data and configuration was migrated.